# Create an associative array from for loop results in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a form that calculates mileage from 4 destinations to one single origin. When submitted, I can display the text that shows the origin and the distance to each destination on a new line, for example:

Margate, UK to Coventry, UK: 177 mi in 3 hours 13 mins
Brighton, UK to Coventry, UK: 158 mi in 2 hours 41 mins
Bristol, UK to Coventry, UK: 108 mi in 1 hour 49 mins
Birmingham, UK to Coventry, UK: 21.8 mi in 31 mins

I want to create an array of this information so I can call it in other functions. For example, I just want the Destination and the miles, so something like this:

{"Margate, UK" => 177, "Brighton, UK" => 158, "Bristol, UK" => 108, "Birmingham, UK" => 21.8}

Here is the code I use to make the for loop:

```
function calcDistance(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

    outputDiv.innerHTML += origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
                + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '
                + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try making an array `const distances = []` and then push into it the desired information in the inner for loop

```
...
var results = response.rows[i].elements;
for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
  distances.push([origins[i], results[j].distance.text])
  ...
}
```

or you could extract the information from the submitted form text using regex

```js
const distinations =
  'Margate, UK to Coventry, UK: 177 mi in 3 hours 13 mins Brighton, UK to Coventry, UK: 158 mi in 2 hours 41 mins Bristol, UK to Coventry, UK: 108 mi in 1 hour 49 mins Birmingham, UK to Coventry, UK: 21.8 mi in 31 mins'

const cities = distinations.match(/\b(?:(?!Coventry)\w)\w+, \w+/g)
const distances = distinations.match(/(?<=: )\d+/g)

const result = []
for (let index in cities) {
  const city = cities[index]
  const distance = distances[index]
  result.push({
    city,
    distance
  })
}

console.log(result)
```